# Javascript dispatchEvent - How to change eventArgs

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome-extension, event-handling, dom-events

I have a custom event that is fired by a certain function.

This event contains an `eventArgs` with detail and so. I wish that the handlers/listeners be able to change the `eventArgs` so the original function gets its changed value. Is that possible?

So far I've tried this:

**Handler/Listener**

```
document.addEventListener('myCustomEvent', function(eventArgs)
{
    eventArgs.detail.value = newValue; // I want the listener to change the value in "e"
});
```

**Caller**

```
var eventArgs = {                   
    detail:         
    {               
        value: originalValue;
    },              
    bubbles: false, //not sure what this does
    cancelable: false, //not sure what this does
};
                                     
document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('myCustomEvent', eventArgs ));   

//do things here with a changed eventArgs after the event is fired
```

The change made in the listener does not reach the caller. I tried also to add complex objects inside `eventArgs.detail`, but in that case, the handler gets a null `eventArgs`.

Is it impossible to accomplish or am I missing something?

---

Important: I'm doing that in a Chrome extension, where the event is fired in a script directly attached to the document, and the listener belongs to the extension code (content script).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vL4re0qr/

Answer (score 1):

That should work, keep in mind you have to call addEventListener, BEFORE the call to dispatchEvent. Javascript passes objects by reference so any mutations are done on the original object.

```
var eventArgs = {
    detail: {
        value: 5
    }
};

document.addEventListener('myCustomEvent', function(eventArgs)
{
    eventArgs.detail.value = 6; // I want the listener to change the value in "e"
});
document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('myCustomEvent', eventArgs));

$('#button').click(function() {
    alert(eventArgs.detail.value);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/polarisjunior/uLwaw924/1/
If you click the button you can see the value is updated.

Comment: Sorry....that does not work. And it's exactly what I'm doing, except for the "calcelable" and "bubbles" (which I removed to test). I think it's about some limitation from the Chrome Extension.... The event is fired at actual document context, while the listener is in the extension context.